# Updating ImageView Frequently in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-ndk

I want to update my ImageView frequently. I have a gallery in which i have multiple images and i am using gallery's **onFling** method to select a image. After the fling complete i have a image view on my screen where i have to show the image which is selected on gallery fling. I am able to update the ImageView with selected image in an separate thread. But when the user continuously scroll the galley and select the images very quickly then a thread start for a each selected image and update the ImageView. But in this updation it takes a long time suppose if the user select 10 images continuously then the ImagesView updates those images one by one in order. I just want that if the user select 10 images continuously then my image view update directly the last image selected.

For any help Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually trying is wrong. You have to make use of Gallery's onItemSelectedListener.

So this method gets called whenever a Image gets selected in your Gallery.

Here is a very nice example of how to achieve this, take a look.

http://mobsandgeeks.blogspot.in/2011/04/image-switcher-example.html

Comment: Thnx for the reply but in ur demo when user moves the gallery items than every time a item is selected and i dont want that ,thts why i am using gallery's onFling method. In onfling method only that item is selected on which fling stops. Thats why i am using onFling method .